# Filtering every Viewset that inherits a Viewset with the Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a viewset like this:

```
class CountryBasedViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        [element that needs to be filtered by country].filter(country=self.request.data["country"])
```

Is there any way in which I can make that element being filtered generic so that it applies to anything inheriting the viewset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the concrete queryset in the child viewsets. But of course, the queryset models need to have a similar API.

```
class CountryBasedViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = None
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.filter(country=self.request.data["country"])

class ViewsetA(CountryBasedViewset):
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()

class ViewsetB(CountryBasedViewset):
    queryset = ModelB.objects.all()
```